# "Their "Is being used in the below sentence for whom? Please reply fast

Tags: meaning, ambiguity

Mental-health practitioners whose clients kill themselves can face stigma from "their colleagues".Whose Colleagues ,their own or the client?

Comment: What's the rush?

Comment: Are the quotes really in the sentence, or did you add them for emphasis?

Comment: i added them for emphasis.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is: **it depends**

The sentence as written is ambiguous.  Both of these sentences are valid:

> Mental-health practitioners whose clients kill themselves can face stigma from their clients' colleagues.
>
> Mental-health practitioners whose clients kill themselves can face stigma from their own colleagues.

"Their" could either refer to "the clients" or it could refer to "themselves".  The only way to know is either rewrite the sentence less ambiguously, or use common sense.

---

Most likely, "their" is referring to the mental health practitioners.  We can probably learn this from the context of the surrounding statements (which would be helpful to provide).

Also, the stigma from a client's colleagues would probably not be too terrible.  Most of my colleagues would probably not even know whether I'm seeking mental help.  More likely, the mental-health practitioners would face stigma from my family over my colleagues.

Lastly, the idea that my friends, family, and acquaintances would be mad at my mental-health practitioner if I commit suicide is not a revolutionary idea.  On the other hand, the idea that mental-health practitioners judge each other when their *client* (not themselves) does something of their own free will *is* at least a more interesting idea.

For these reasons, the sentence likely is referring to the mental-health practitioners' colleagues.

Answer (score -2):

Colleagues of the practionner. See how you could take out the bit about clients:

Mental-health practitioners whose clients kill themselves can face stigma from their colleagues.

Mental-health practitioners can face stigma from "their colleagues".

Answer (score -2):

Take out "whose clients kill themselves", which only modifies Mental-health practitioners, and you get:

Mental-health practitioners can face stigma from "their colleagues".

Their refers to Mental-health practitioners.

Comment: but I'm bothered by the quotes around "their colleagues", which are unnecessary.

Comment: Suppose it said _lawsuits from their families_. Wouldn't you then interpret it to refer to the clients' families? It's common sense, not the syntax, that determines the meaning.

Comment: Indeed. The conclusion is probably right, but the argument is _utterly_ wrong. _Their_ is an anaphor (word that refers back), and the rules for determining what it refers to are difficult, and don't necessarily give a definite answer. But removing or adding words before it  can certainly affect what it refers to, and there really is no reason for supposing that it won't.